# Overflow-wrap for long text strings: a bug in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I've come across what looks like a bug in Chrome when I try to apply the `overflow-wrap: break-word` CSS rule to break a long (very long) string into multiple lines:

Here's an example (on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2toweyk7/2/)) using nucleotide sequence of a human gene (~85,000 characters long). I am displaying it in a container with the following CSS properties:

```css
.sequence {
  margin: 20px;
  height: 480px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-y: auto;
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 60ch;
}
```

What you will see is that Chrome overestimates the width of each line to be wider than the width of the container, and creates a horizontal scrollbar as a result (screenshot below). In my development environment (can't replicate this in the toy example on jsfiddle) I am also seeing that the last line of the sequence remains unwrapped and expands past the width of the container (which is why I can't simply apply `overflow-x: hidden` to the container, if you are wondering).

[image]

You will also find that both Firefox and Safari are wrapping this gigantic string correctly, properly calculating the width of every line.

So my questions to you are:

- Have you seen this behavior on Chrome before? Do you know if it's a known bug?
- Barring `overflow-x: hidden` on the container, is there any way to make Chrome wrap such long strings over multiple lines correctly? Am I missing some obvious CSS fix?

Comment: I dont see any wrong behavior from any browser

Comment: Using chrome I see the problem : https://imgur.com/a/FbpkJzB

Comment: It might be due to a specific Chrome + OS combo. The screenshot I posted in my question is from Chrome on MacOS; but now that I am checking in Chromium on Linux, I am not seeing the problem.